# Batch file to delete specific files in multiple folders

Tags: loops, batch-file

I need to delete specific files from 28 folders on the same server.
e.g

C:/folder/DMP/app_x0

C:/folder/DMP/app_x1

C:/folder/DMP/app_x2

DeleteList.txt has a list of files names (with path).

C:/folder/DMP/app_x0/ABC1.txt

C:/folder/DMP/app_x0/ABC1.doc

The batch file needs to have a loop to go through each folder one by one and delete all files mentioned in a text file. Following worked ok for one folder only if I specify the full path before each file's names in  DeleteList.txt file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (DeleteList.txt) do del "%%f"
```

How to use above so that same code could run 28 times in batch file but each time replaces folder location path. DeleteList.txt will not change.

Any sample code/suggestion would help.
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these questions where we need to read between the lines.

Given we have on file of full filenames with the incorrect path separator, and a requirement to delete the files from 28 directories (but there's no list) then I conclude that since the required subdirectories shown are all subdirectories of `C:\folder\DMP\` then the requirement actually is to delete all of the files that match the filenames in the file in all subdirectories of the parent directory of the full filename in the list.

So my suggestion would be

```
 for /f "delims=" %%b in (DeleteList.txt) do del /s "%%~dpb..\%%~nxb"
```

Naturally, you should test this on a dummy tree before implementing it.

`del /s` deletes in the target directory and all subdirectories. The target subdirectory is the drive and path of `%%b`; its parent (`..`); the name and extension part of `%%b`.

I prefer to use metavariables that are not available as metavariable-modifiers.

To delete in subdirectories but not in the parent:

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in (DeleteList.txt) do FOR /d %%c IN ("%%~dpb..\*") DO del /s "%%c\%%~nxb">nul
```

This time, `%%c` is set to all subdirectorynames in turn, and the `del/s` applied to each subdirectory. The `/s` (...and subdirectories) probably isn't required. The `>nul` suppresses the deletion report if desired.

Comment: Thx, it does work but it deletes all files even in the parent folder and subfolders. What needs to do to make sure it only deletes files listed in DeleteList.txt in the subfolder only?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the OP has need for this anymore, but you can use the following batch script to delete the specific files from multiple folders, starting from a parent folder.

```
@echo off
for /r "Drive:\path\to\parent_folder" %%d in (.) do (
  del "%%~d\ABC1.txt"
  del "%%~d\ABC1.doc"
)
```

The script will loop through the parent directory and its sub-folders, and delete only the specific files from the folders that they appear.
In the case of the post, the parent folder can be "C:\folder".